# In Azure as a Resource Group contributor why can't I create Storage Accounts and what should be done to prevent this situation?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

A Subscription admin at a customer granted me (an MS account) Contributor role on one of their Resource Groups.

When I try to create a Storage Account in that Resource Group, I get a failure that:

> 'AuthorizationFailed' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/register/action' over scope

I logged into the Subscription via Powershell and listed the available providers, and found that most are not registered.
When I try to register, I get that error.

Why are they not registered? What should the admin do to correct this? What should be done in future to avoid this problem when adding Contributors? Right now as a Contributor in that RG, I can't do very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I logged into the Subscription via Powershell and listed the available
>   providers, and found that most are not registered. When I try to
>   register, I get that error.

The reason you're getting this error is because th Subscription Administrator has put you in `Contributor` role on a particular resource group. They have not granted you any permission on `Microsoft.Storage` resource provider. In order for you to register the subscription with this resource, you would need `Write` permission on `Microsoft.Storage` resource provider.

You can either ask your Subscription Administrator to give you appropriate permissions or they can register the subscription with that resource provider.

**UPDATE - Follow Up Questions**

> my understanding was that Contributor role simply allowed the
>   specified user to create resources in the group.

Your understanding is correct. With a `Contributor` role in a resource group, you should be able to create resources in there.

> At one point in this role assignment does the Subscription
>   administrator specify which resources can be created and which not? 
>   Or is it that the limitation is somehow on the way the Subscription is
>   set up?

Well yes and no. So if you're assigned some blanket role like `Contributor` you should be able to create any kind of resources. However with `Custom Roles`, an administrator can get super creative and only allow you to create resources of a certain kind. However the Subscription should be registered with a resource provider before a resource of a kind can be created.

The way I understand this whole thing is structured is that each product team in Azure is responsible for providing their own functionality. The central point in all of this is `Azure Resource Manager` which provides amongst other things `Role-based Access Control`.

Let's take Azure Storage for example. The functionality to interact with storage accounts (from management perspective like creation, deletion etc.) is provided by Storage Team using something called `Storage Resource Provider (SRP)`. So if you look closely, there's a resource provider for each and every feature. For reasons unknown to me, not all resource providers are available to you by default (could be the cost reason) and a Subscription Administrator must register his/her Subscription with that resource provider so that resources of that kind can be created in that Subscription.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I think I need some further clarification...my understanding was that Contributor role simply allowed the specified user to create resources in the group. At one point in this role assignment does the Subscription administrator specify which resources can be created and which not? Or is it that the limitation is somehow on the way the Subscription is set up?

Comment: Let me update my response to answer your questions as it's going to be somewhat lengthy one :)

Comment: OK great, looking forward :-)

Comment: "For reasons unknown to me, not all resource providers are available to you by default (could be the cost reason) and a Subscription Administrator must register his/her Subscription with that resource provider so that resources of that kind can be created in that Subscription."
Ah....I see....In the past as a Subscription admin, when I added Storage Account, the registration must have been happening behind the scenes. Now as a Contributor that background registration process is surfacing. It seems like an oversight on the Azure team's part to me.

Comment: The "required registration" is intentional -- less surface area by default and some RBAC flexibility for admins (though it manifests itself otherwise at times as you've experienced :)).  There are a few places where you don't notice because the tools do this for you automatically (PowerShell, Portal) when you create a resource or deploy a template.  If nothing has ever been created in a subscription though, this is what you'll see.

Comment: @bmoore-msft The scenario turns out to be that up until now the admin (subscription owner) had been using Classic mode for things. After creating resource groups and adding me as Contributor, these problems arose. Please could you point us to some step by step guide for just granting access to all these providers that the admin can use? Some walkthrough? I think this should be default for Contributor, or at least plain in the portal that the option is there.

Comment: This: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-supported-services/#resource-providers-and-types - will show you how the admin can check what's registered or not and how to register using PowerShell or CLI (there's a link to the REST API as well).

Comment: OK I checked this, and I feel it does not make sense. The obvious thing to do is give the Contributor the same "auto register" behavior as the (former role) subscription co-admin, and/or make this configurable in the portal. Thank you for the information, I will refer this to the admin, but I can't help feeling that this is just not what should be happening.