# Azure Blob Container Granting Read only Access through Shared Access Signature Access

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have two Azure Blob Storage containers. Container A and B. I would like to grant Read only access to another Azure User for Container-A. The second container Container-B should not be visible to the Azure user. The Azure user will be accessing the blobs in Container-A from his Azure Virtual Machine. How do I achieve this? Reading on the web seems that I would need to generate Shared Access Signature, but how I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, that is the scenario where you want to use SAS. 
First, please read the [Azure Storage security guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-security-guide/) to make sure that you are aware of all of the available options.
[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) is the very helpful guidance on the SAS model.

Second, you need to generate the SAS with policies (please, refer to the guidances above). It can be done programmatically (sources are available in the guidance) and then you may give that SAS link to user you want anyway you want - it can be the online page where the user can grab the string, or you can write the simple tool to generate the SAS. Be aware, however, that they have the "life" and you need to renew them periodically.

Comment: it is such a weird way of granting an access. Is it not possible to do it like an Active Directory Style access i.e. User X, Y and Z can access Container-A. Instead of giving Users a same URI. This way you would not know which User accessed it would you?

Comment: You may use the role model as described in that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023313/in-azure-as-a-resource-group-contributor-why-cant-i-create-storage-accounts-and/37023551#37023551 using resource groups. Or, as described in the security guidance, you may set the roles for different storage accounts. I am quite sure it can not be used on the container-level.

Comment: Here is the RBAC description - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/ . You may grant the user1 role of a reader, and user2 role that has the write access.

Comment: It seems that the Role Based Access can only be used at Storage Account Level but not at the Container Level. Is this correct? If it is then is it true that it is not possible to implement scenario where User X can only Access Container A and not Container B?

Comment: I am quite sure that without SAS it is not possible.