# Azure RBAC based access to Storage Account

Tags: azure

I have a Service Principal that has been granted Contributor roles on a storage account.

When I attempt to create a container within that account I receive the following error message

```
One-time registration of Microsoft.Storage failed - The client 'd38eaaca-1429-44ef-8ce2-3c63a62849c9' with object id 'd38eaaca-1429-44ef-8ce2-3c63a62849c9' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/********'
```

My goal is to allow a Service Principal READ-ONLY to the blobs contained within a given storage account and to create containers within that storage account. What are the steps needed to configure my principle to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error, please see this thread: [In Azure as a Resource Group contributor why can't I create Storage Accounts and what should be done to prevent this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023313/in-azure-as-a-resource-group-contributor-why-cant-i-create-storage-accounts-and).

> My goal is to allow a Service Principal READ-ONLY to the blobs
>   contained within a given storage account and to create containers
>   within that storage account. What are the steps needed to configure my
>   principle to do that.

As of today, it is not possible to do so. Simply because RBAC only applies to the control plane of the API. So using RBAC, you can control who can create/update/delete a storage account. Access to the data inside a storage account is still controlled by an account key. Anyone who has access to the account key will have complete control over that storage account.

Comment: What are the steps to allow a Service Principal to create container and blobs within a storage account. I read the other link but unfortunately it didn't make much sense to me. I echo the sentiments of the other question asker - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023313/in-azure-as-a-resource-group-contributor-why-cant-i-create-storage-accounts-and#comment61639366_37023551

Comment: In particular I'm trying to use Azure with our config management system , as described here - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/azure_rm_storageblob_module.html which app